# write a parsed response from a json file in a div

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

let's say that I have a json file like this: http://www.example.com/json?jsonp=parseRespond

My HTML code:

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/json?jsonp=parseRespond"></script>
```

http://www.example.com/json?jsonp=parseRespond respond is:

```
{"id":"5572a7d648b33a462d79145d","avatarHash":null,"bio":"","bioData":null,"confirmed":false,"fullName":"Ender Widgin","idPremOrgsAdmin":[],"initials":"EW","memberType":"normal"}
```

How can I get the parsed respond header ? 
Here is what I have tried so far:

```
 var _request = undefined;
 var headers = _request.getResponseHeaders();
 document.write(headers);
```

But , it doesn't work!

**Note: I am not doing XMLHttpRequest because Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

**Note: I am not using callback=apiStatus as it redirects to an unauthorized link.**

so the only way I can get response is when using jsonp=parseRespond , how can I write that response in a div ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using **JSONP** to handle the data received from the server, you need to write your own function `parseRespond` which takes that data as an argument and, perhaps, print it to the particular DIV you want.

Given the URL:

```
http://www.example.com/s.json?jsonp=parseRespond
```

You'll need to write a function entitled `parseRespond` like follows

```
function parseRespond(data){
    // data is the response you received from that URL
    // e.g. data = {
    //     name: "John", 
    //     surname: "Conor",
    //     titles: ["Resistance Leader","Survivor"]
    // }

    // encapsulate, format or do something with the data here
    var output = data.name + " " + data.surname + " as " + data.titles.join(",");

    // Then print the output to your DIV like this example:
    $("#mydiv").html(output);
}
```

**NOTE**: JSONP is a JSON with callback, the term you specify in `jsonp=func` leads to a function callback pointing to `func`. Further information you may want to read is well organized and discussed in this thread:

[What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

Comment: thanks , but the response I received looks like this: `{"id":"5572a7d648b33a462d79145d","avatarHash":null,"bio":"","bioData":null,"confirmed":false,"fullName":"Ender Widgin"}`